# How to get addresses of SQL Server cluster nodes through sql query

Tags: sql-server, windows-clustering

Is there any way to get addresses of cluster's nodes via SQL query for SQL Server cluster?

Comment: What kind of cluster, failover or load balancing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the below links

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/eb2e7260-e408-4daf-b72a-8d05109266b5/find-ip-address-and-detail-of-cluster-sql-instance?forum=sqldisasterrecovery

[SQL - Query to get server's IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142142/sql-query-to-get-servers-ip-address)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c9ef1a7b-65f9-4556-9db4-94bedc190e6a/find-ip-address-and-detail-of-cluster-sql-instance?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade