# Which IP to Use to Remote Connect to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I am trying to remotely connect to a Microsoft SQL Server from Node (using node-mssql).

```
var sql = require('mssql')

var config = {
  server:   '**',
  user:     '**',
  password: '**!',
  database: '**'
}

sql.connect(config, function(err) {
  var request = new sql.Request()
  request.query("select *", function(err, recordset) {
    console.log(err)
    console.log(recordset)
  })
  console.log('end')
})
```

I ran the following query from the server:

```
SELECT  
   CONNECTIONPROPERTY('net_transport') AS net_transport,
   CONNECTIONPROPERTY('protocol_type') AS protocol_type,
   CONNECTIONPROPERTY('auth_scheme') AS auth_scheme,
   CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_net_address') AS local_net_address,
   CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_tcp_port') AS local_tcp_port,
   CONNECTIONPROPERTY('client_net_address') AS client_net_address
```

based on [SQL - Query to get server's IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142142/sql-query-to-get-servers-ip-address)

Do I use the `client_net_address` to remote connect, or some other IP for the `server` parameter?

Comment: The `server` property defines the remote server address (The remote MS-SQL server).

Comment: Yes, but how do I locate the correct address?

Comment: Currently I have to VPN into the network and then use another IP to connect to to the SQL database.

Comment: Why wouldn't you try it with the `client_net_address` property? I can't really understand what you mean..

Comment: If you have to use a VPN to access the network of the SQL database, are you sure the SQL database is even exposed to the internet?

Comment: @jkaufman No, I'm not sure if it's exposed to the internet.  I'm trying to figure out the process to set up an external IP for the db and access it remotely.

Comment: @TamirNahum I tried using ```client_net_address``` and the connection was refused.

Comment: I'm afraid you're confused as to how this works. You shouldn't be trying to attempt to determine the IP address from the MSSQL server, as it will only be able to provide you with a local IP address specific to your network, hence the need for you to use a VPN to access it. You must determine the public IP of the machine that the server is running on, and ensure that it has internet access. If it does, then you need to ensure the port that MSSQL listens on is open, as well as allowing traffic through the firewall.

Comment: OK.  Do I use the VPN username and password for the ```config``` connection string?

Comment: Do I need to use IIS to configure anything?

Comment: You would not use the VPN username or password for the MSSQL connection string, no. You would want to use the username and password for the MSSQL server. But before you can do that, you must make sure that the server is exposed to the internet. That may be through IIS as a reverse proxy, or it may be directly via the system itself.

Comment: I setup a reverse proxy with the ```client_net_address``` to the remote connection ip changing only the last digits ```xxx.xxx.xxx.100``` and using the SQL database credentials, and it's still not connecting.

Comment: Using these instructions: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If connecting from an application on the same machine, use the `local_net_address`.