# How can I get the IP address of an EF Core DbConnection/DbContext?

Tags: azure, entity-framework-core

I want to track the IP Address a specific EF Core DB Connection is using to connect to Azure SQL. Can I do that?

I tried looking at the properties of DbConnection and DbContext but didn't see anything useful. Is it maybe possible to downcast to SqlConnection to get this information? What is the right way to do that?

Comment: I assume it's just using DNS lookup from the server name. However that probably points to a server farm with multiple ip addresses.

Comment: Yeah, I'm debugging an issue where I think two requests are going to different servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use extension method `GetConnectionString()`

```cs
var connectionString = context.Database.GetConnectionString();
```

Or you can access to DbConnection:

```cs
var dbConnection = context.Database.GetDbConnection();
```

In case if SQL Server is under balancer, for getting IP aggress, you should execute SQL query on opened connection as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14695530/10646316)

Comment: @PoulBak, you are right, added this part.

Comment: So my understanding here is that I can only get the IP address via SQL statements, not through DbConnection?

Comment: Tried to dig into SqlClient source code and then private properties, with no luck. IP Address retrieved from `Dns.GetHostEntry` and used for creating TCP Socket is not accessible.